# T-test, Chi-squared test and hypothesis testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, chi-squared-test

I am not an expert in the field of statistics and my questions might be stupid, please be indulgent :)

I've come across many videos/articles about T-test that suggest sampling data when their dataset is not big at all.
Now, when it comes to collecting data, or dealing with an extremely huge dataset, I get it.
However if my dataset is 50000 or even 500000 rows, with today's computational power, what's the point ? If the data is already collected and ready to use , why not use it ?
I have also read someone mention that if I use my whole dataset, then I can just compare the populations means and don't really need to do a T-test.

My case : I want to know whether or not the age difference between a customer and a call center agent could affect sales performance. My data is basically 2 columns : age_difference and sale_made( yes or not ). I then divided it in 2, one dataset being the sales made, the other one being the sales not made. I want to do a T test to know if the distributions are different.

My questions :

1. Why would I just compare just the populations means without any test when using the whole dataset ? I indeed have a small difference in the means of the 2 populations, but how can I be sure that this is not just random/luck if I don't do any test that will give me a p-value ? Shouldn't a p-value be always welcome to draw some conclusions ?
2. Why would I sample my data ? (for sample size 50, I don't reject H0 -> same distribution, for sample size 90, I dont reject H0 -> same distribution, for sample size 100 and above, I reject H0 -> different distributions ). Sample size clearly have an impact on my conclusion and more data gives more evidence that the distributions are different.
3. Now about Chi-squared test, in the same project, I am trying to know whether the sex of the call center agent and the customer could affect the sales. I am doing a Pearson CHi squared test with scipy chi2_contingency function.
   I have read so many times that one should choose the significance level before doing anything else. So I decided to choose the usual alpha = 0.05, I have 1 degree of freedom, I can read in the Chi squared distribution table the corresponding threshold (3.84). My test gives a chi_squared test statistic = 3.67 so I don't reject H0. Now it may be a stupid question, but why does changing the significance level after a first test seems to be such a big deal ? if I choose alpha = 0.1, the corresponding threshold  in the table = 2.71 and I now reject H0. Why couldnt I use this as an insight ? i mean, 10% of error can still be acceptable in many cases. Someone could argue that I should have chosen this significance level from the start if it's enough for my work, and that's right. But people can make mistake and do better the next time ! It's just trial and error ... After all the point is just to get useful insights from the data. So again, why does it seem to be such a big deal and such a big mistake to change the significance level ?

Thank you for reading this, I hope that I  didn't sound too ignorant and that someone will be able to give me some insights.

Comment: Sampling data when the dataset is not big? What do you mean?

Comment: You are asking too many questions. I recommend splitting your question into several posts. As for the age difference hypothesis. I wouldn’t use t-test. It doesn’t take into account the actual age of the two people involved only the difference. I would recommend logistic regression using formula sale_made ~  age_customer + age_agent + |age_customer-age_agent|. The significance of the last term is the answer.

Comment: As for the point 1). Probably best way is to stop using the population-sample metaphor. It’s often used in textbooks for non-mathematicians who want to use statistic methods. I consider it severely detrimental. Commonly used statistical tests weren’t derived to handle population/sample problems. The underlying theory is all about making hypotheses about parameters of random variables not about estimating population characteristics. I recommend reading something about the logic of testing statistical hypotheses. It also helps you to deal with questions 2) and 3).

Comment: @Dave I have seen "courses" where someone uses a T-test to compare the sales of 2 shops in 2 different countries. The data is not so big ( around 70 rows in each dataset ) and he would take samples of size 30 from each to perform the test. Unless you have millions of rows, I really don't understand why

Comment: All I can think is that the instructor is demonstrating on a small data set what one would do on a large data set. If I had 70 valid observations, I would use all 70, not a subset of 30.

Comment: @DanielDostal Thanks for your answers, I have started reading more in-depth explanations on the topic. Your suggested approach is interesting and I will give it a try. However, since the age difference can be positive or negative ( and maybe the sign could affect the outcome in different ways ), is it really suitable to use the absolute value ?

Comment: *come across many videos/articles about T-test * can you link/reference some of those?